# ACL allow IP range Squid

Tags: ip, squid

I'm using Squid and I want to know how to make a specific IP range of allowed connections, I use this

```
acl permittedips src 77.86.72.49

http_access allow permittedips
```

But I want to make an range that allows from `70.*.*.*` to `90.*.*.*`. How can I do this the easiest way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use CIDR notation to signify this in the ACL for squid.  You would want:

```
acl permittedips src 70.0.0.0/8
acl permittedips src 90.0.0.0/8
```

More information on CIDR:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIDR_notation

Comment: This doesn't seem to work? My IP is `86.132.x.x` and I can't connect to squid, it works if I put my oringinal IP address, but I want to specify the range **BETWEEN** `70.*.*.*` to `90.*.*.*`.

Comment: Oh, I missed the 'to' part.  You really can't do that easily with CIDR, you'd be best off adding 20 rows one for 70, 71, 72...89, 90.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. When I restart squid, it tells me `start: Job failed to start`. On `service squid start`.

Comment: You probably need to give different names to each block, like permittedips70, permittedips71

Comment: @polynomial No, it is possible to use same acl name for multiple lines. He should look into squid `cache.log` for errors.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is a very old thread but since it still shows up on Google when searching for squid ip range I am going to give a new answer that worked for me.

Squid allows you to specify a range of ips in accordance to:

**acl permittedips src 1x.x.x.x-2x.x.x.x**

So in this case:

**acl permittedips src 70.0.0.0-90.255.255.255**